Wi-Fi randomly stopped working - network UNCLAIMED
Out of the blue earlier today my Wi-Fi stopped working, no warning whatsoever, (not even after a restart I don't think.) Anyways, the title says it all, lshw -C network outputs:
*-network UNCLAIMED       
     description: Network controller
     product: MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
     vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:3d:00.0
     version: 00
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: iomemory:610-60f iomemory:610-60f iomemory:610-60f memory:6105000000-61050fffff memory:6105100000-6105103fff memory:6105104000-6105104fff

After a bit of Googling, I am led to belive that the driver for my card stopped working, but I can't find any drivers for it anywhere. I am hesitant to go the NDISwrapper route, as I'm not sure if it will lead to any issues further down the line. I also know that the card was working just fine before, so I'm sure there is a way to resolve this without it.
In the meantime, I'm using USB tethering through my phone, but it isn't the most sustainable solution, and has its own downsides, so I would love a full resolution.
Thanks so much!
